# Why does this file give me "syntax error: I give up." in verilog program?

Tags: verilog, testbench

This is my original file saved as "example.v"

```
module example(a,b,y);
  input b,y;
  output a;
  assign a=b&y;
endmodule
```

This is my testbench file saved as "example_tb.v"

```
module testbench; 
    reg t_x, t_y; 
    wire t_z; 
    example DUT ( t_z, t_x, t_y ); 
    initial 
        begin 
            $dumpfile(“example.vcd”); 
            $dumpvars(0, testbench);
            $monitor ($time, "t_x=%b, t_y=%b, t_z=%b",t_x, t_y, t_z); 
            #5  t_x = 1’b0; t_y= 1’b0; 
            #5  t_x = 1’b0; t_y= 1’b1; 
            #5  t_x = 1’b1; t_y= 1’b0;
            #5  t_x = 1’b1; t_y= 1’b1; 
            #5  $finish;
        end 
endmodule
```

Command I runned:

```
iverilog -o mysim example.v example_tb.v
```

Error reported:

```
example_tb.v:7: syntax error
I give up.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your apostrophe chars are the problem

```vhdl
 $dumpfile(“example.vcd”);
```

should be

```vhdl
 $dumpfile("example.vcd");
```

And for all the literals, such as,

```vhdl
#5  t_x = 1’b0; t_y= 1’b0;
```

they should be

```vhdl
#5  t_x = 1'b0; t_y= 1'b0;
```

Comment: Typical copy-paste bug!